# Woocommerce custom category page shows all the categories instead of only the selected one

Tags: php, woocommerce

Im new to the php and wordpress/woocommerce editing. I didnt create this code but i was asked to create single category pages. 
This code, i think, creates a loop of categories repeating each category element existing.That forms our all categories page, but now i need to create single category pages.. Please help

```
 <?php
        $args = array(
            'number'     => $number,
            'orderby'    => 'title',
            'order'      => 'ASC',
            'hide_empty' => $hide_empty,
            'include'    => $ids
        );
        $product_categories = get_terms( 'product_cat', $args );
        $count = count($product_categories);
        if ( $count > 0 ){
            foreach ( $product_categories as $product_category ) {
                $category_id = $product_category->term_id;
    ?>
```

Comment: might this be spam?

Comment: Please consider paring your code dump down to a [mcve], or at least try to indent it more reasonably.

Comment: I didnt write this code, i was just asked to correct the problem and i am stuck XD but im almost certain that the issue lies in the beguinning at the foreach. It keeps looping the content to all pages regardless of category

Comment: Your code is indented with tabs, which my browser is displaying as eight spaces, which means parts of your code are outside the display element. You should try to write a shorter bit of code to demonstrate your problem, and indent it with two or three spaces per level, so it's easier to read.

Comment: Can you read it properly now?